# getting same content in all csv files

Tags: python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, python-requests

Here is my code:

```
wardName = ["DHANLAXMICOMPLEX", "POTALIYA", "ARJUN TOWER", "IIM"]

def get_all_pages():

    global wardName
    list = []
    url = 'https://recruitment.advarisk.com/tests/scraping'
    client = requests.session()
    tree = html.fromstring(client.get(url).content)
    csrf = tree.xpath('//input[@name="csrf_token"]/@value')[0]
    for i in wardName:
        formData = dict(csrf_token=csrf, ward=i)
        headers = {'referer': url, 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'}
        r = client.post(url, data=formData, headers=headers)
        list.append(r.content)
    return list
def parse_and_write_to_csv(htmls):
    global wardName
    parse = html.fromstring(htmls)
    th = parse.xpath("//table[@id='results']/thead//th//text()")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmls, "html.parser")
    table = soup.select_one("#results")
    for i in wardName:
        name = str(i) + '.csv'
        with open(name, 'w') as fw:
            writer = csv.writer(fw)
            writer.writerow(th)
            writer.writerows([[j.text for j in i.find_all("td")] for i in table.select("tr + tr")])
def main():
   for value in get_all_pages():
       parse_and_write_to_csv(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but as you can see all CSV file contains same content of last IIM page. I want to get each CSV file to get content according to their name. What should I do to get correct CSV? Where I'm getting wrong?

Comment: "as you can see"... No, I don't see that

Comment: bro, it's creating CSV files which have same contents and as there is no option to upload CSV file, therefore, i can't show you that

Comment: Csv is plaintext.. Copy and paste the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within `for i in wardNames` both `writer.writerow` usages never changed their content between iterations

You need to move these lines into that loop and change them if you want to have different CSV contents

```
th = parse.xpath("//table[@id='results']/thead//th//text()")
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmls, "html.parser")
table = soup.select_one("#results")
```

---

One suggestion would be to add the wardName to its result

```
list.append((i, r.content))
```

And loop over those

```
for ward, page in get_all_page():
    write_to_csv(ward, page)
```

And redefine your function to not loop over the wards again

```
def write_to_csv(ward,page):
    parse = html.fromstring(page)
    th = parse.xpath("//table[@id='results']/thead//th//text()")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    table = soup.select_one("#results")
    with open (ward+'.csv', 'w') as f:
       # write csv
```

---

Another suggestion is to remove the global list.

```
def get_page(ward):
    pass 
def write_ward_csv(ward, ward_html):
    pass 

for ward in [ ... ]:
    write_ward_csv(ward, get_page(ward))
```